# How to modify/replace all the store in mobx-state-tree?

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am working on a React Native project and mobx state tree. I would like to modify the store every time I call a store action. For example:

```
const store = types.model({
  user: types.maybe(User)
  settings: types.maybe(Settings)
})actions((self) => {
 
   updateUsername(username: string) {
     // Call to the Native SDK to update the user.
     const userUpdated = SDK.updateUsername(username);

     // Update user node.
     applySnapshot(self.user, userUpdated);
   },

})).create();
```

After updating the user, the app crashes. The nodes are replaced, so if I am in a component that receives the user or one of its sub-nodes, the app says that I am trying to read/write a component that it's not part of the tree anymore.

How can I update a node/nodes and render again the component if the store changes?

Let me know if you need more information, thanks!

Comment: [It seems to be working nicely](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-dew-1i2yr?file=/src/App.js). Do you think you could provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I was not declaring an identifier for each deeper model, so the reconciliation didn't work properly. Thanks.